# CodeIgniter - file upload doesn't see file

Tags: codeigniter

I'm creating upload functionality, but I want it to be a part of a bigger function, like this:

```
public function addGame() {
    // validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Tytuł gry', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dsc', 'Opis gry', 'required');

    $data['title'] = 'Dodaj grę';

    $this->load->model('contrib_model');
    $this->load->model('games_model');

    // image upload
    $config['upload_path'] = './img/';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data['submit'] = $this->contrib_model->addGame($this->input->post()); //submits data
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('cover')))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            print_r($data);
        }
        $this->load->view('contribute/emptyPage', $data); //loads view
    } else {
        $data['genres'] = $this->games_model->Genres();
        $data['platforms'] = $this->games_model->Platforms();
        $data['developers'] = $this->games_model->Developers();

        $this->layout->view('contribute/addGame', $data); //loads view
    }
}
```

And my form:

```
<li><input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Tytuł gry" class="required"></li>
<li><textarea name="dsc" id="dsc" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Opis gry" class="required"></textarea></li>
<li><input type="text" name="dsc_src" id="dsc_src" placeholder="Źródło opisu" class="required"></li>
<li><input class="required" type="text" name="reldate" id="reldate" placeholder="Data wydania (RRRR-MM-DD"></li>
<li><input type="file" name="cover" id="cover" class="required"></li>
```

My problem is that it says that there is no file specified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line is throwing that error?  Have you been able to debug?

Comment: The only error is "You did not select a file to upload.". Which I did.

Comment: Is the form open tag something like this: `<?php echo form_open_multipart('yourcontroller/addGame');?>`?

Comment: Yes, `<?php echo form_open_multipart('contribute/addGame', 'id="addGame"'); ?>`. Form itself works - values are added to database, only images aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement should actually read

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('cover'))
```

instead of

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('cover')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a fresh WAMP installation. Turned out that HTTP file uploading was off in my php.ini file. So make sure it's on.

```
file_uploads = On
```